# Socket listener is KILLING my CPU, how to improve performace of my code?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, listener, port

I Have implemented a Socket Listener to read data sent from a GPS, but it is consumming 90% of my CPU. I know it's my code causing this, but I cant see where.

This is my main Class:

```
public class PortToDB {

    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

    public void listenSocket(){
        try{
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(50000);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not listen on port 50000. " + e);
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        while(true){
            GPSData gd;
            try{
                gd = new GPSData(serverSocket.accept());
                Thread t = new Thread(gd);
                t.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Accept failed: 50000. " + e);
                System.exit(-1);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        PortToDB portToDb = new PortToDB();
        portToDb.listenSocket();
    }
}
```

This is my Runnable Class:

```
class GPSData implements Runnable {

    private Socket client;
    DBHandler dbhandler = new DBHandler();

    GPSData(Socket client) { this.client = client; }

    public void run(){
        String line;
        BufferedReader in = null;

    try{
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("in or out failed");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    while(true){
      try{
          if((line = in.readLine()) != null){
              dbhandler.dbInsert(line);
          }
      } catch (IOException e) {
          System.out.println("Read failed");
          System.exit(-1);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) may be able to help/a better place to ask.

Comment: How many threads are getting created overall, how often, and how many are running at the same time? Does high CPU use start immediately after some use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `readLine()` returns `null` you must close the socket, exit the read loop, and forget about that client. You are spinning at EOS.

Comment: I'm sorry what does EOS mean?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of creating new thread for each incoming request, use a thread pool:

```
private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(15);

// ...

gd = new GPSData(serverSocket.accept());
executor.submit(gd);
```

This way, you will eliminate the overhead of creating unlimited threads at the time of receiving requests and instead creating limited threads even before opening the socket port to receive the requests.

---

Also, as @EJB said, exit the client for-loop whenever you receive `null` from `readLine()` as an indicator of the end of the stream (EOS).

Comment: What if the number of connections is exceeding 15??

Comment: You could also add a small Thread.sleep in the read thread. This should reduce some of load and allow some of the other threads an opportunity to process there data

Comment: Wont' that lead to overhead for other waiting Connections??

Comment: I will try this ringht now.

Comment: @VishalK Then increase the number of threads. It is a matter of tuning :)

Comment: I always wonder why such flexible ThreadPool is not provided in java concurrent package..Or perhaps i have still to go in depth of `util.concurrent` package..!! :)

Comment: @VishalK There is another flavor of this executor, `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`.

Comment: @MadProgrammer What do you mean?

Comment: @MadProgrammer. Right...OP thread is using `while(true)` loop ..and it is continously reading the data .. So this thread(or connection more precisely) wont be closing untill the connection is closed by client itself or just because of some network error..

Comment: @VishalK That's how server applications usually work, just serving the clients.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: wow..such method existing just below my nose..and I hadn't noticed it...!!! That's great..i think OP should use `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` indeed.. but again the situation will be same as what OP is facing without using this `Threadpool`

Comment: This is all irrelevant. He doesn't need a sleep in the read thread. Read is a blocking operation. Changing to a thread pool won't solve a problem of 100% CPU usage.

Comment: Thread pooling will help, but what would be more helpful is to avoid the endless loop in the code... see @EJP's answer.

Comment: The endless loop is ment to make this run forever, since this applications will be a service running endlessly.

Comment: @Felemed It can't run forever beyond the peer disconnecting, and your endless loop must detect and exit on that case.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad actually I've Implemented the piece of code with executor and it stays under 50% for a while but then escalates to a steady 98-99%

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who answered my question.

I've solved this by combining Eng.Fouad's and EJP's suggestion:

This is what I Changed in my code:

Executor:

```
    private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(15);

    try{
        gd = new GPSData(serverSocket.accept());
        executor.submit(gd);
    }
```

Looping control:

```
    try{            
        while((line = in.readLine()) != null){         
        dbhandler.dbInsert(line);
        }
    }
```

Now the process stays stuck at 0% :).

Thanks EJP and Eng.Fouad.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad I'd like to know if you guys agree with this.

Comment: @EJP I'd like to know if you guys agree with this.

Comment: I agree with *my* answer. I don't agree that you need a thread pool. *at all,* unless you are accepting hundreds or thousands of connections per second, when all you said was '*a* GPS'; and I certainly don't agree with a fixed size thread pool of 15, unless you only want to service 15 clients at once and let the rest wait, which also isn't mentioned in your question.

Comment: @EJP I understand what you are saying, but I'll have to be more specific. In this particular case I'm testing A (one) GPS connection with  approximately 50 seconds between each update, I am now developing inside a developing machine. When this goes to production there will be (as far as today) 45 GPSs updating approximately each 1-2 minutes. I'm not sure about how to calculate the exact amount of threads I should implement in the thread pool, but 15 seems like a good margin to allow this some growing space. I'm open to more information so far you have been very helpful.

Comment: @EJP I agree with you that the endless loop in the client code is the cause of the 100% CPU usage, but I disagree with you when you said that the OP does not need a thread pool. What about the overhead of creating a new thread for each incoming request?!

Comment: @Eng.Fouad The original question said *a* GPS, which implies *one* client and therefore *one* thread, started *once*. The fact that he can survive with a fixed thread pool of 15 threads indicates that he doesn't have heavy new-connection traffic. Thread-creation overhead is therefore not an issue. I would certainly advocate a thread pool if there was any evidence that he needs one, but there isn't.